# How to import private data with GitHub actions?

Tags: node.js, github, github-actions

I'm working on a Node project involving several API keys. I stored the API keys in a configuration file `config.js`. Then I added `config.js` to `.gitignore` so that the API keys aren't revealed in the public repository. But when I try to `npm run build` with GitHub actions, there's an import error because `config.js` isn't in the repository.

Can I "simulate" `config.js` somehow on GitHub? Or should I setup an action to download `config.js` from elsewhere? Is there a better approach?

I'm using GitHub's boilerplate `nodejs.yml`:

```
name: Node CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [8.x, 10.x, 12.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - name: npm install, build, and test
      run: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present
      env:
        CI: true
```

I'm fairly new to CI/CD. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I solved this problem using the accepted answer below. I stored `config.js` in a secret variable `config` on GitHub. Then I added a step in the workflow that creates `config.js` before it's needed:

```
  ...
    - name: create config.js
      run: echo '${{ secrets.config }}' > path/to/config.js
    - name: npm install, build, and test
  ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could declare your key as a [secret in GitHub Actions](https://developer.github.com/actions/managing-workflows/storing-secrets/) under the name you want (for instance '`my_secret_key`')
See also "[Creating and using secrets (encrypted variables)](https://help.github.com/en/articles/virtual-environments-for-github-actions#creating-and-using-secrets-encrypted-variables)"

Said key can be referenced in your `config.js` as a variable `$my_secret_key`.